# MariaDb Begin End in a multi-value Insert

Tags: sql, mariadb

Im using MariaDb and Im trying to execute a multi-value insert query using Begin End and I get the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1  0.000 sec`

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO Client (Id, Name, Total) 
VALUES
(1, 'John', 1000),
(2, 'Mary', 3000),
(3, 'Mike', 14000),
(4, 'George', 15000);
END;
```

Can I use Begin, End with a multi-value insert and if yes what is the correct syntax here?

I have millions of data to insert. the above is just a small sample of my dataset

Comment: you can't finish an insert statement with a trailing `,` in the value list. Also `BEGIN`/`END` aren't needed. Are you following a guide for a different SQL server?

Comment: @danblack I accidentally added comma instead of semicolon. ```BEGIN/END``` according to MariaDb optimizes inserts up to 1000 times. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/

Comment: @pantonis, yes, transaction optimizes *multiple-statement* updates. But transaction with *single* statement does not optimize anything. I'd suggest you just do the multi-insert, which is the best fast-insert optimization.

Comment: so multiple-statement with BEGIN/END is faster than single statement?

Comment: From 10.7+ there is underlying assistance [described in this blog](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-innodb-bulk-insert/).